# DateTime convertion in java

Tags: java, datetime, youtube-api

I have a date get saved in the database in IST format.

```
     Date nowDate = new Date();
     Date dateBefore = new Date(nowDate.getTime() - 7* 24 * 3600 * 1000);
     System.out.println("Datebefore-->"+dateBefore);
```

Here in the above code dateBefore is get saved in the database.

From the database I am taking the data long value and I have to convert this into Google **DateTime**

```
     Date dateBefore12 = new Date(longvalue); 
    com.google.api.client.util.DateTime dd = new DateTime(dateBefore12, TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```

Now for example the output will be in the `2014-07-17T05:23:28.857Z` which I have to pass to the Google You tube API.

Now from the response I will take Google DateTime, let say `2014-07-17T05:23:28.857Z`  which I have to increment the 1 minute and then convert it into long and save into db.

Convert the google DateTime to long.

```
 TimeZone utc = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
    SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
    String input = dd.toString();

    GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(utc);
    cal.setTime(f.parse(input));
    cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE,1);

    Date time = cal.getTime();
    long longvalue1 =cal.getTimeInMillis();
```

Now I will saved the data and try to retrieve it. It gives me back `2014-07-16T23:54:28.857Z`.

But I need the save date value which I have increment by one minute in the format of google DateTime.

Answer (score 0):

`SimpleDateFormat` also uses a time zone, due to an internal `Calendar` object, which defaults to the local time zone. If you don't want to use that default time zone, then before you call the format's `parse()` method, you should call `setTimeZone()` on it:

```
f.setTimeZone(utc);
```